# Is there any documentation about how Minix 3.2 (latest) boot?

Tags: bootloader, minix

I found this site: http://www.os-forum.com/minix/boot/
which claims to document the boot sequence of Minix.

But in the source tree of Minix 3.2 I just get from Git, the files described in the above site simply don't exist.

They are:

```
masterboot.s
bootblock.s
boothead.s
boot.c
bootimage.c
rawfs.c
```

Does Minix change the way it boots?

Is there any documentation about how Minix boot itself?

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone vote for close, please give a reason and don't do that anonymously.

Comment: The website you link to is referring to the second edition of the book from 1997 and likely not at all relevant for Minix3. And no, I didn't vote for closing. Actually I find the question interesting.

Comment: Thanks. I want to analyze a true micro-kernel OS, so I turn to Minix. But the boot sequence turns out to be quite a secret. If someone one really wants Minix to be popular, why make it so unnecessarily obscure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That web page talks about Minix as described in the second edition of *Operating Systems*, i.e. Minix 2. The equivalent documentation for Minix 3 is [on the Minix wiki](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/DevelopersGuide/FromPowerOnToLoginPrompt). Some of that is also out-of-date, as -- in 3.2 -- [Minix adopted the NetBSD bootloader](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/MinixReleases).

There is some documentation [how NetBSD boots](http://wiki.netbsd.org/how_netbsd_boots_on_x86/), but it's not a good as the site you're talking about. For source, start looking in this folder: https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/tree/master/sys/arch/i386/stand

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How I wish THE "Andrew" could see this question...  :)